# MiniMagick - cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm trying to use MiniMagick to resize images and I did the following in my controller file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mini_magick'
```

and

```
img = MiniMagick::Image.open(file)
```

But when I invoke the controller the following

```
LoadError (cannot load such file -- mini_magick)
```

I've added `gem 'mini_magick'` to my Gemfile so I have really no idea what's going on. Can someone help me with this?

BTW, it is available in both `irb` and `rails console`, but not when run as a server.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Are you running the server from the command line (i.e., rails server) or through an IDE?

Comment: I'm using unicorn to run it @DaveIsaacs

Comment: Hmmm, if you were running through an IDE I was going to suggest making sure your IDE is running in an environment equivalent to the command line. I don't know anything about Unicorn, however :(

Comment: @DaveIsaacs Solved by restarting my server.. Thanks anyway~

Answer (score 27):

Dammit, restarting the server solved it..

Comment: :D "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" should be a prerequisite checkbox when submitted a StackOverflow question.

Comment: For rails project , yes.

Comment: Laughing in coding midnight. :)

Comment: please accept the answer, so that others find the solution easier, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Add `gem "mini_magick"` to your Gemfile

and restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

```
gem 'image_processing'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue.
Just uncomment the line

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
```

in your uploader file and make sure you have commented the line

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick
```

So your setting in uploader file should look like this:

```
# include CarrierWave::RMagick
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times this problem is caused by not having the latest version of the gems. It can be fixed by running bundle update.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have this error just add `gem "mini_magick"` and restart your server using the `rails s` command. But most importantly, remember to always check your server logs on your terminal for the error message. They are your best friend in figuring out the solution you need for your problem.